# How to give boundaries to cities in google map according to the city typed in the text box by a user

Tags: javascript, google-maps, asp.net-mvc-4

I know that this type of question has been asked multiple times and I have also gone through many tutorials but still I don't get how to mark boundaries of a city that the user has selected. I also tried to draw a circle and a polygon but nothing seems to work for me. I have never worked with Google maps before so any help will be appreciated.

Code for Google map:

```
<!DOCTYPE link href="https://maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<html>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    var mapcode;
    var diag;
    function initialize() {
        mapcode = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var lnt = new google.maps.LatLng(14.6928, -17.4467);
        var diagChoice = {
            zoom: 9,
            center: lnt,
            diagId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        diag = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), diagChoice);

    }
    function codeAddress() {
        var add = document.getElementById('address').value;
        mapcode.geocode({ 'address': add }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                diag.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var hint = new google.maps.Marker({
                    diag: diag,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
            } else {
                alert('This code is not successful ' + status);
            }
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
<body>
    <div id="panel">
        <input id="address" type="textbox">
        <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="codeAddress()">
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas" style="height: 450px; border: 5px solid #5E5454;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, a user can enter a city name in the text box and he will get the map of the desired city with the help of the function codeAddress(). I want to display boundaries for that city. How should I do it?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this library for do that easily:

https://github.com/pgkelley4/city-boundaries-google-maps

Comment: Thanks. I will surely try it

Comment: In this example I tried to input various cities and states but it always gives the alert stating 'Couldn't retrieve the city limits for a city, they are either missing from OpenStreetMap, not labeled consistently or the city entered is not valid.'